# Logarithmic Darboux theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Let $X$ be a smooth complex analytic manifold and $D$ be a normal crossing divisor. Suppose that there is a complex analytic logarithmic symplectic structure on $X$.

Is there a Darboux like theorem that says that the  complex  analytic log symplectic form on a neighbourhood of a point is $\sum_{i=1}^r \frac{dx_i}{x_i}\wedge dx_{i+r}+\sum_{j=1}^{2(n-r)-1} dx_{2r+j}\wedge dx_{2r+j+1}$, where $\{x_i\}$'s are some local complex coordinates of $X$ and the divisor is given by the vanishing locus of $x_1\cdots x_r$?

If this is a known result an explanation or a reference of the proof will be very helpful.

Comment: For b-symplectic manifolds (i.e. $r=1$), a Darboux theorem is established in https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05303

Comment: @Tobias Diez thanks